Key error in TWS API for python while incrementing nextOrderId
I'm trying to trade multiple stocks at a time that meet the same conditions for a trade. To track the data, I'm storing the data in a dictionary using the nextOrderId as the key, and the contract details and bar data as the values. While incrementing the nextOrderId, I get a key error.
The nextOrderId seems to be incrementing fine for the stocks I have in a list, but then it makes one more incrementation than I need. I think that's what's triggering the error. I was expecting the incrementation to happen only when there is a stock in the list. I'm not sure how to avoid this.
import ibapi
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
import ta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import threading
import time


port = 7497


BAR_TRACKER = {}
ACCOUNT_INFO = {}
class ibapi(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)
        self.nexOrderId = 1
        self.contract = (0, Contract())
        #self.data = {}

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: OrderId):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId

    def contractDetails(self, reqId: int, contractDetails: ContractDetails):
        self.contract = (reqId, contractDetails.contract)
    
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderReject = ''):
        print(f'reqId: {reqId}, errorCode: {errorCode}, errorString:{errorString}, order reject: {advancedOrderReject}')

    def historicalDataUpdate(self, reqId, bar):
        if reqId not in BAR_TRACKER:
            BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId] = (self.contract, [])
        BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId][1].append((bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume))

    #def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        # Store historical data
        #if reqId not in BAR_TRACKER:
            #BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId] = (self.contract, [])
        #BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId][1].append((bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume))

    #def realtimeBar(self, reqId, time, open_, high, low, close, volume, wap, count):
        # Store real-time data
        #if reqId not in BAR_TRACKER:
            #BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId] = (self.contract, [])
        #BAR_TRACKER[self.nextOrderId][1].append((time, open_, high, low, close, volume))

    #def requestData(self, contract, isHistorical=True):
        #if isHistorical:
            #self.reqHistoricalData(self.nextOrderId, contract=contract, endDateTime="", durationStr="2 D", barSizeSetting="1 min", whatToShow="TRADES", useRTH=1, formatDate=1, keepUpToDate=False, chartOptions=[])
        #else:
            #self.reqRealTimeBars(self.nextOrderId, contract=contract, barSize=5, whatToShow="TRADES", useRTH=True, realTimeBarsOptions=[])
    
    def updateAccountValue(self, key: str, val: str, currency: str, accountName: str):
        if key == "CashBalance":
            ACCOUNT_INFO[key] = float(val)

    def updatePortfolio(self, contract: Contract, position: Decimal, marketPrice: float, marketValue: float, averageCost: float, unrealizedPNL: float, realizedPNL: float, accountName: str):
        ACCOUNT_INFO[contract.localSymbol] = {"contract":contract,"position": float(position), "marketPrice": marketPrice, "marketValue": marketValue, "averageCost": averageCost}
        
    def openOrder(self, orderId: OrderId, contract: Contract, order: Order, orderState: OrderState):
        print(f"openOrder. orderId: {orderId}, contract: {contract}, order: {order}")
    
    def execDetails(self, reqId: int, contract: Contract, execution: Execution):
        print(f"execDetails. reqId: {reqId}, contract: {contract}, execution: {execution}")

def buildContracts(app: ibapi, tickers: list):

    reqId = 1
    contracts = []
    for symbol in tickers:
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = symbol
        contract.secType = 'STK'
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        contract.currency = 'USD'
        
        app.reqContractDetails(reqId, contract)
        requested = True

        while requested:
            if app.contract[0] == reqId:
                contracts.append(app.contract[1])
                requested = False
                reqId += 1
            
    return contracts


def marketMonitor(app: ibapi, contracts: list):
    for contract in contracts:
        app.nextOrderId += 1

        app.reqHistoricalData(app.nextOrderId, contract=contract, endDateTime="", durationStr="2 D", barSizeSetting="1 min", whatToShow="TRADES", useRTH=1, formatDate=1, keepUpToDate=True, chartOptions=[])
        #app.requestData(contract, isHistorical=True)
        #app.requestData(contract, isHistorical=False)
        

def porfolioMonitor(app: ibapi):
    app.reqAccountUpdates(True)
    

def tradeStrategy(app: ibapi):
    for contract in BAR_TRACKER:
        ohlcv = BAR_TRACKER[app.nextOrderId][1]

        print(ohlcv)

    order = Order()
    order.orderType = 'MKT'
    order.tif = 'GTC'
    order.outsideRth = True

    while True:
        for contract in BAR_TRACKER:
            ohlcv = ohlcv = BAR_TRACKER[app.nextOrderId][1] #key error thrown here
            mycon = BAR_TRACKER[app.nextOrderId][0]
            app.nextOrderId +=1

            #trading logic
def main():
    app = ibapi()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', port, 1001)
    time.sleep(3)
    app_obj = threading.Thread(target = app.run)
    app_obj.start()

    porfolioMonitor(app)
    tickers = ['QUBT','SGMT']
    contracts = buildContracts(app, tickers)

    marketMonitor(app, contracts)

    time.sleep(5)

    trd_obj = threading.Thread(target=tradeStrategy, args=(app,))
    trd_obj.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


while True: seems to be an endless loop. It probably results in going through for contract in BAR_TRACKER: more than once.

That was it. It's running now. Thank you1
